# Make a partially hidden div show up the full content

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, each

I would be thankful if you could find a solution for me. I have a list of articles each one in a partially hidden div (div is 200px height). When I click on readmore it should nicely slide down showing up the rest of the content.

Here is the html:

```
<style>
    .content {height:200px;}
</style>    
<div class="content_1">Full text here...</div><a href="" class="readmore"></a>
<div class="content_2">Full text here...</div><a href="" class="readmore"></a>
<div class="content_3">Full text here...</div><a href="" class="readmore"></a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code (it works but only for content_2:

```
var len = $('.wrap > .content').length;
  $("a.readmore").click(function(event){
    var hiddenContent = $(".wrap > .content_2");
   event.preventDefault();
   hiddenContent.animate({
    height: '500px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

  });
```

How do I iterate over ".content_"+i so I can make it work for the specific div I click?
I tried looping with each, for etc...but I got no luck

Comment: Your using IDs where it should be a class and classes where you should be using IDs ..... IDs should be unique and classes can be used on multiple DOM elements

Comment: Im also confused as to where your content is loaded from ? and where is .wrap ? perhaps try to add a http://jsfiddle.net to help us understand your problem ?

Comment: Yeah..sorry. This is a mistype I made only here. The content is being loaded from a database of articles. It loads the full node not a trimmed one but it hides a part of it and dispplay it after you click read more..

Answer (score 0):

You can select a previous element in jQuery really simply. Here's a script that will show the content and then hide it if the user clicks on the readmore link a second time. It also changes the link label. jQuery makes it all really straight forward:

```
$("a.readmore").click(function(e){
    if($(this).prev("div.content").hasClass("open")){
        $(this).prev("div.content").animate({"height":50}).removeClass("open");
        $(this).html("More...");
    }else{
        $(this).prev("div.content").animate({"height":500}).addClass("open");
        $(this).html("Less...");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here's the jsfiddle live example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/JmLqp/

Comment: Thank, you made my day. I carefully examined your code and indeed the prev() function is very very useful here. Blessed be you!